# Remove the return const qualifier in the const version of array subscript operator overloading []?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, subscript

Is it acceptable to remove the "const" qualifier in the return type in a return-by-reference array subscript operator overload?

Something like

```
template<typename Value>
struct enclosedarray
{
 Value* actual; //newed, etc
 size_t nel;
 ...
 Value& operator[](size_t index) { return actual[index]; }
 *const* Value& operator[](size_t index) const { return actual[index]; }
 ...
}
```

where the `*const*` is removed (it compiles in g++) can be passed as a const-reference, right?

```
const enclosedarray<bigstuff> cebig{big1,big2,big3}; 
cebig[2]=big4; // compiles, no problem
```

and you can pass the reference to a function that will change the value

`processbigstuff(cebig[1]);`

where

```
void processesbigstuff(bigstuff& abigstuff)
{
  abigstuff=anotherbigstuff;
}
```

The idea is to provide a "slice" akin to a Fortran "array segment" as:

```
auto operator[](std::pair<size_t,size_t> indices) const 
{ 
  return enclosedarray{actual,indices.second-indices.first}; 
}
```

Since the returned object is not a constant now but it will be as an argument of a function, will this make sense?

```
void processsegment(segment)

with 

void processesssegment(const enclosedarray<bigstuff>& segment )
{
  // here it goes the non-const return const member function in segment 
  segment[1]=anotherbigstuff;
...
}
```

The fact that removing the "const" return in the const member function is allowed without warning from the compiler appears as intentional.

Was this intentional? Is this an acceptable use of this feature?

Do you need a separate class for the slices?

Thank you.

The idea is to replicate an intermediate "constness" of an array as it exists in Fortran. You can change the values stored in an array with slices (array segments in Fortran), but to allocate or deallocate it no slices are allowed to be passed. Trying to do it in C++ but it doesn't look a legitimate use of this language. At least I couldn't find an explanation or advice.
Oddly, the compilers (clang++ and g++) do not complain when the const in the return reference is removed for the const function.

Comment: Tag fortran95 is very rarely used and makes no sense when you mention Fortran 2003. Just use tag fortran like you use tag c++ and not c++-11 or c++-21.

Comment: Thank you, just removed the reference to the Fortran version.

Comment: It's a question about C++. How you can use the same effect for array slices (or segments) in C++. Thank you!

Comment: There's a plethora of questions getting asked here. One question per Stackoverflow question, please. If "it's a question about C++", then can you [edit] and reframe your question as a single question, make it more focused; additionally, unless something about Fortran that's crucial to understanding a single, focused C++ question what Fortran does or does not would be completely irrelevant.

Comment: OK, I will change it, but it's only one question. It would be useful to replicate what Fortran does with "array segments" for a lot of people doing computational physics or computational mechanics with C++. Thank you.

Comment: Removing the leading `const` is valid in C++, and will allow the caller to change the object via the reference (in your case, the element `actual[index]` if it exists). The trailing `const` prevents the `operator[]()` itself from changing the members `nel` or `actual`, but doesn't prevent using the caller using the returned reference to change `actual[index]`. Whether that's "acceptable" or not is (in general) a matter of opinion or (in specific cases) a consideration in intended/designed usage of your class.  *Personally* I would not remove the leading `const` without a specific reason.

Comment: There is a convention that returning a reference from a const object method also makes the referred object const. But that's only a convention. For instance a `const vector` returns a const reference when accessing elements in it even though elements are prohibited from being stored as const. constness can then be cast away w/o UB.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, that's a big help.

Comment: After some days of thought, it now appears that it may be more precise to define two or three related classes with varying degrees of "constness" instead of using the const-qualifier in one of the functions. Something like: "enclosedarray", "constenclosedarray" and "constconstenclosedarray". WDYT ?